# How to check if a date is a specific day in the week in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, weekday

I have a MySQL table `presence` with following structure:

- id: 1
- uid: 14
- start: 2021-11-01 00:00:00
- end: 2021-12-31 00:00:00
- repetitive: 1

This row gives me the information, that the user 14 is present every Monday from 2021-11-01 to 2021-12-31.

```sql
SELECT 1
FROM presences
WHERE 2021-11-15 BETWEEN DATE(`start`) AND DATE(`end`)
```

checks if the given date (2021-11-15) is between his presence dates but how can I add logic to check for "every Monday"? Additionally, if `end` is null, it should check for every Monday in future without end.
Monday is given by `start` date and can be every other day as well.
`repetitive` gives me to check that given day by `start`. If `repetitive` is 0, it should just check like my query already does, if the date is between `start` and `end`.

Human query: get all rows from `presence` table where given date is between start and end (if end is not null) and where given day is day of start.

Comment: `weekday(start) = 0` to check for Monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get all rows from presence where given date is between start and end,
> if end is not null and where given day is day of start.

could be humanly translated to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE '2021-11-15' >= `start`
AND (
    '2021-11-15' <= `end` OR
    `end` IS NULL
)
AND (
    repetitive = 0 OR
    repetitive = 1 AND WEEKDAY('2021-11-15') = WEEKDAY(`start`)
)
```

Comment: I like the `OR end IS NULL` very much. What I miss is, when `repetitive` is `0`, it should just check, if the given date is between `start` and `end`. If it is `1` your query will work

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for. The only thing that's missing is, that end can be NOT NULL but repetitive can be 1. Than it should check between start end it every day.

Comment: Can't edit anymore. So: If start and end is given, query must check between start and end. If end is null, query must check from start until infinity. If repetitive is 1, check weekday. if 0 check every day.

Comment: I think it does exactly that. I will re-arrange the brackets a little to make it clear.

Comment: It does: https://paiza.io/projects/u7hLgpPBz5LGtZib2-XOjQ?language=mysql Thank you!

Comment: I just would add date() around `start` and `end` to really ignore time, in the case given date is a full timestampo

Comment: I removed date cast to keep it simple. But ideally you should use `date` datatype for start and end, if they are in fact dates. Using `date(datetime_column)` in where clause can reduce performance.

Comment: Is it possible to check between date AND time if Y-m-d H:i:s is given and check date only, if Y-m-d is given?

Comment: If the given date is `2021-11-01` and your data contains datetime `2021-11-01 10:00 AM` then it won't match `>=` :(

Comment: but it should mach, as there is no time in the given date. If I add a time (optional) then it should pass for `2021-11-01 11:00 AM` bur fail for `2021-11-01 09:00 AM`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238863/discussion-between-john-doener-and-salman-a).

Answer (score 0):

Directly answering the question posed in the title of your post you can use:

- [DAYOFWEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)(*date*): Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard.
- [WEEKDAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday)(*date*): Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).
- [DAYNAME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname)(*date*): Returns the name of the weekday for date. The language used for the name is controlled by the value of the lc_time_names system variable

But in your description of the query you want, you say

> Get all rows from presence where given date is between start and end, if end is not null and **where given day is day of start**. (my emphasis)

which implies you want the number of instances of `start` date day name/index in your range. To do this you can use different methods to extrapolate your range to rows and the pick the required day from it.

A calendar table would be best, as you can already build in the day name/index in to the data in the table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as monday_count
FROM presences JOIN calendar
  ON calendar.day_date BETWEEN DATE(`start`) AND DATE(`end`)
WHERE `end` IS NOT NULL AND calendar.day_name = DAYNAME(`start`);
```

Here's an [example of building a calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), it's MSSQL specific so some of the queries might need to be modified for MySQL, but you get the idea.